# AngularDart Popup Component

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

[image]
[image]How should I implement Popup of angular_components on user profile image in AngularDart.

https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example/#Popups
This link of examples helped me to know about AngularDart components and about their implementation, but I am still unable to implement it on a user profile image. So can anyone help me to know how should I do that

Thank you in advance.

app_header.dart

```
@Component(selector: 'app-header',
templateUrl: 'app_header.html',
styleUrls: const ['app_header.css'],
directives: const [
  MaterialButtonComponent,
  MaterialPopupComponent,
  PopupSourceDirective,
  DefaultPopupSizeProvider,
],
providers: const [
  popupBindings,
  DefaultPopupSizeProvider,
],)


class AppHeader {
final FirebaseService fbService; 
bool headerFooterPopupVisible = false; 

String get tooltipMsg => 'All the best messages appear in tooltips.'; 
String get longString => 'Learn more about web development with AngularDart'
  'here. You will find tutorials to get you started.';

AppHeader(FirebaseService this.fbService);
}

@Injectable()
PopupSizeProvider createPopupSizeProvider() {
return const PercentagePopupSizeProvider();
}
@Directive(selector: '[defaultPopupSizeProvider]', providers: const [
const Provider(PopupSizeProvider, useFactory: createPopupSizeProvider)
])
class DefaultPopupSizeProvider {}
```

app_header.html

```
<header class="navbar-dark bg-primary layout horizontal center justified">
<div class="horiz">
<div id="chat-bubble" class="icon"></div>
<a class="navbar-brand">Dart Chat</a>
</div>

<div class="horiz">
<div id="sign-in" *ngIf="fbService.user == null" class="horiz">
  <div id="google-icon" class="icon"></div>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" 
(click)="fbService.signIn()">Google Sign In</button>
</div>

<div id="sign-out" *ngIf="fbService.user != null" class="horiz">
  <div id="user-name">{{fbService.user?.displayName}}</div>
  <img class="icon" [src]="fbService.user?.photoURL">

  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" (click)="fbService.signOut()">Sign Out</button>

  <material-button class="blue"
                   raised
                   popupSource
                   #headerExampleSource="popupSource"
                   (trigger)="headerFooterPopupVisible = !headerFooterPopupVisible">
    {{headerFooterPopupVisible ? 'Close' : 'Open'}} Custom Popup
  </material-button>
  <material-popup defaultPopupSizeProvider
                  enforceSpaceConstraints
                  [source]="headerExampleSource"
                  [(visible)]="headerFooterPopupVisible">
    <div header class="custom-header">
      This is a Header demo
    </div>
    <div class="custom-body">
      Hello, Hello, Hello. This is a tall bit of content that needs a scroll
      bar because the content is so long.
    </div>
    <div footer class="custom-footer">
      This is a Footer demo
    </div>
  </material-popup>

</div>
```

If I am using the following code.

Error: DirectiveProcessor on dart_chat_ng2_fb3|lib/views/app_header/app_header.dart]:
ERROR: Template parse errors: line 25, column 7 of AppHeader: ParseErrorLevel.FA
TAL: Void elements do not have end tags "img"

^^^^^^
[Error from TemplateCompiler on dart_chat_ng2_fb3|lib/views/app_component/app_co
mponent.ng_meta.json]:
Could not find Directive/Pipe entry for name: AppHeader
. Please be aware that Dart transformers have limited support

```
<img [src]="fbService.user?.photoURL" class="blue"
                   raised
                   popupSource
                   #headerExampleSource="popupSource"
                   (trigger)="headerFooterPopupVisible = !headerFooterPopupVisible">
    {{headerFooterPopupVisible ? 'Close' : 'Open'}} Custom Popup
  </img>
  <material-popup defaultPopupSizeProvider
                  enforceSpaceConstraints
                  [source]="headerExampleSource"
                  [(visible)]="headerFooterPopupVisible">
    <div header class="custom-header">
      This is a Header demo
    </div>
    <div class="custom-body">
      Hello, Hello, Hello. This is a tall bit of content that needs a scroll
      bar because the content is so long.
    </div>
    <div footer class="custom-footer">
      This is a Footer demo
    </div>
  </material-popup>
```

and if I simply change the "material-button" tag to "button" the popup didn't show up

Comment: What's the problem? What is the actual behavior? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: If the html tag is changed in any of the other rather than material-button the popup is not working

Comment: What html tag have you tried? What does "not working" mean exactly? Do you get an error message, or does the popup just now show up?

Comment: I have updated the question with the error, kindly go through the question.

Comment: Permitted content None, it is an empty element.
Tag omission Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Popup didn't shows up.                                                                        
 <img class="blue" [src]="fbService.user?.photoURL"
                       raised
                       popupSource
           role="button"
                       #headerExampleSource="popupSource"
                       (trigger)="headerFooterPopupVisible = !headerFooterPopupVisible"/>

Comment: `<img>` has no `trigger` event. Change it to `(click)="..."`

Comment: Yes it worked thank you so much. I am totally a newbie in programming started with AngularDart, and also AngularDart is the first language I am learning.

Comment: It's fine. The information you provided in the question and comments allowed to track the issue(s) down. This is the most important part.
I hope you enjoy working with Dart and Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from the template, if you read this part:
`Void elements do not have end tags "img"` it will point you to the problem - there should never be `</img>` tag, as the `<img>` can never contain content.

Some details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img